# How to put all the three portions in same line when reducing the screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to coding as well as stack overflow and below mentioned is the code, and I am trying to bring both the icons in the same line as the brand logo and menu when reducing the size of screen.

Below mentioned is the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-justified">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#"><img src="images/zigsaw.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center navbar-header">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li><a href="#" class="badge badgeq"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="badge badgeq"><i class="fa fa-comment fa-2x " aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.badgeq {
    display: flex;
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #35BBE6;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.badge:after {
    content: "100";
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(0,0,255,1);
    height: 2rem;
    top: 0rem;
    right: 0.5rem;
    width: 2rem;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox defines how flex items are laid out inside a flex container. Flex items are positioned inside a flex container along a flex line. By default there is only one flex line per flex container. So, you can try the bellow structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```